# Add Class to Laravel 4 Package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, namespaces

I am using this Laravel 4 package for interacting with the Xero accounting application: https://github.com/Daursu/xero

In the GitHub README, it says that you can extend the package easily by using the following code:

```
namespace Daursu\Xero;

class CreditNote extends BaseModel {

    /**
     * The name of the primary column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primary_column = 'CreditNoteID';
}
```

I tried adding this as a new Model, but Laravel gives me a `Class not found` error.

I'm assuming this is a namespacing issue a but can't seem to get it right. I have tried using `\Darsu\Xero` and also `\Darsu\Xero\BaseModel`, and other various combinations with and without the initial `\`.

Any tips on how to do this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easiest way to achieve your intentions:**

1) Create a file `CreditNote.php` in `app\models`

2) Put the following code in the above file:

```
use Daursu\Xero\BaseModel;

class CreditNote extends BaseModel {

    /**
     * The name of the primary column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primary_column = 'CreditNoteID';
}
```

3) Whenever you need to use the `CreditNote` model, use `$creditNote = new CreditNote();`

Comment: I removed my almost identical answer - seems I got to this question about an hour after Mysteryos did.

Comment: Is there an error in the way the author of that Xero library explains how to extend his BaseModel in his docs?